# Future is returning empty List

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My below code is returning an empty list, even though it SHOULD return data corresponding to my data stored in my firestore database. Also to note: The otherUserId print statement is not getting printed. How can I fix this issue?

```
 Future<List<String>> getChattingWith(String uid) async {
  List<String> chattingWith = [];
  try {
    // create list of all users user is chatting with
    final rooms = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('rooms')
        .where('users', arrayContains: uid)
        .get();
    for (final room in rooms.docs) {
      final users = room['users'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final otherUserId = users['uid1'] == uid ? users['uid2'] : users['uid1'];
      print("otherUserId999: $otherUserId");
      chattingWith.add(otherUserId);
    }
    print("chattingWith: $chattingWith");
    return chattingWith;
  } catch (error) {
    print("error: $error");
    return [];
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So it jumps in the catch block? What is the error?

Comment: No, it just prints "chattingWithList: []"

Comment: So your room.docs is empty, can you check it?

Comment: No, it is not empty. I am trying to fetch all rooms where the users array contains the uid. After that I create a list of the user ids which are not equal to the uid. So basically I want to create a list of all uids which a user is chatting with. But the data is fine, just the query is not working.

Comment: I have added an image of the users array. Maybe my query is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code does not match your data structure:

```
final rooms = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('rooms')
    .where('users', arrayContains: uid)
    .get();
```

Your `users` is a `Map` and not an array, so `arrayContains` won't work here. As said in my answer to your previous question, you have to use dot notation to test nested fields:

```
final rooms = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('rooms')
    .where('users.uid1', isEqualTo: uid)
    .where('users.uid2', isEqualTo: otherValue)
    .get();
```

That  is closest to what you tried in your previous question: [Firestore conditional array query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330311/firestore-conditional-array-query). It performs an AND condition on the `uid1` and `uid2` subfields of `users`.

If instead you want to get all rooms that the user is a participant in, you need an (additional) field that is an array with the UIDs of all participants.

```
participantUIDs: ["uid1", "uid2"]
```

Then you can do:

```
final rooms = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('rooms')
    .where('participants', arrayContains: uid)
    .get();
```

Comment: The GOAT himself. Thank you a lot for your time and help! Learned a lot today thanks to you!