# How to check if data matches field in array in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore configuration as show below:

[image]

How would I check if `eventParticipants`'s contains a uid matching the current user's uid? The below code used to work when `eventParticipants` used to be an array of user id's, but since creating more detailed array objects, the code seems to not work:

```
data["eventParticipants"]
        .contains({
  "uid": FirebaseAuth
      .instance.currentUser!.uid
      .toString()
})
```

Usually the above code would return a bool, and I would use the result in a ternary operator to load a widget, however, I am unable to rework the logic with the new array structure. Subsequently, how would I remove an array object if it's `uid` field matches the current user's id?

```
FirebaseFirestore
    .instance
    .collection(
        "events")
    .doc(document.id)
    .set(
  {
    "eventParticipants":
        FieldValue
            .arrayRemove([
      {
        "uid": FirebaseAuth
            .instance
            .currentUser
            ?.uid
      }
    ])
  },
  SetOptions(
      merge: true),
);
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `arrayRemove` (and `arrayUnion` and `arrayContains`) operators expect you to pass the complete, exact contents of the item in the array. In your case it looks for an item in the array with a single field `uid` with the value you pass.

So unless you know the values of all properties of the array item that you want to remove, you'll have to:

1. Read the document with the array in it.
2. Manipulate the array in your application code.
3. Write the entire array back to the database.

Also see:

- [Firestore, how to structure a "likedBy" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49010760/firestore-how-to-structure-a-likedby-query/49055526#49055526)
- [Firestore conditional array query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330311/firestore-conditional-array-query/74330603#74330603)
- [Firestore array-contains-any is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052349/firestore-array-contains-any-is-not-working-properly/59053018#59053018)